# How to compute similarity using the log-likelihood similarity metric with mathematics formula?

Tags: math, similarity

```
Item   101 102 103 104 105 106 107     Similarity to User1
user1   x   x   x                             0.9
user2   x   x   x   x                         0.84
```

`x` means the item is selected

I want to know how to compute the  log-likelihood similarity? I know Mahout can solve it, however, I do not know the code inside it and still feel puzzle about its mathematics process.
How can I get 0.9 and 0.84?

Answer (score 4):

https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/package-summary.html

this gives 2 links about LogLikelihoodSimilarity. If these doesn't helps, then you can try to decompile these classes and check it's code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am afraid that most codes have been encapsulated.

Comment: Hm... ok here is source for that :) http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.mahout/mahout-core/0.6/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/LogLikelihoodSimilarity.java

It looks like it's older version than currently, but it should give you basic idea.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/mr/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/similarity/LogLikelihoodSimilarity.java
The source code is now all public on GitHub